# MySQL : Subquery return more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an Insert query with a SELECT_LAST_ID, when executed I get an error saying the subquery returns more than 1 row. this is the query:

```
INSERT INTO categoriesshares (categoryId, userPosted, shareText, isPic, shareTime, isSub) 
VALUES (@categoryId,@userPosted,@shareText, @isPic, @shareTime, @isSub); 
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Here is the full code:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connString);
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand com = con.CreateCommand();
                com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO categoriesshares (categoryId, userPosted, shareText, isPic, shareTime, isSub) " +
                          "VALUES (@categoryId,@userPosted,@shareText, @isPic, @shareTime, @isSub); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@categoryId", (isSub) ? Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["subcat"]) : Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["cat"]));
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userPosted", User.Identity.Name);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shareText", shareText);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isPic", false);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@shareTime", shareTime);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isSub", isSub);

                int newItemId = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
                con.Close();
```

what might be the problem?

Comment: There is no subquery in this code and could possibly produce this error.

Comment: There's more to this... Please post the code where you are loading all those `@` variables, as it's probably one of those causing the error. There is no subquery in the posted code

Comment: And where you extract the data to be inserted into the table...??

Comment: I added the full code

Comment: The error must come from somewhere else. There's nothing here resembling a subquery.  This would come from a problem such as using `column = (select...)` when an `IN ()` is appropriate `column IN (select...)` or a similar situation.

Comment: I understand that the error should come from another type of queries but for some reason I get it from this one, at first I thought it might be something about the SELECT_LAST_ID but couldn't find any problem with that. this really is all the code

Comment: What happens if you remove the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`? I am unfamiliar with how VB treats multiple `;` delimited queries.

Comment: also after removing the SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() still returns the same error, it's c# not VB

Comment: you should use the method `com.ExecuteNonQuery()` for your insert operation. `com.ExecuteScalar()` would be right for your `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

Comment: I did changed it when tested it without the SELECT_LAST_ID still for some reason it returned the "subquery returns more than 1 row" then i tried restarting both the mysql server and the IIS server and still everything remains the same

Comment: @Kadosh: a shot in the dark: have you got a trigger for this insert?

Comment: Yes I do, I will check that direction, the trigger actually has subqueries